'EnrollHash' object is not subscriptable : Query on AWS Django
This is my part of the code:
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
@validate_api_request
def processCommand(request):
    jsonResponse = dict()
    jsonResponse["status_code"] = 200
    jsonResponse["message"] = "Command Sent Successfully"
    jsonResponse["data"] = dict()
    if 'childhash' in request.POST and request.POST['childhash'] \
            and 'command' in request.POST and request.POST['command']:
        usrcommand = request.POST['command'].lower()
        childhash = request.POST['childhash']
        enrollhash = EnrollHash.objects.filter(hash=childhash).filter(
            status='enrolled').first()  # apply simple and condition
        if not enrollhash:
            jsonResponse["status_code"] = 404
            jsonResponse["message"] = "Invalid Child Hash"
            try:
                failedCommand = FailedCommand(childHash=childhash, status_code=404, commandData=jsonResponse)
                failedCommand.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                pass
            requests.post("http://mesh.stg.familytime.io//mdm/checkout", data={"child_mdm_hash": childhash})
            return JResponse(jsonResponse)
        try:
            child = Child.objects.get(enrollHashId=enrollhash.id)
        except Child.DoesNotExist:
            child = None
        except Child.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            child = Child.objects.filter(enrollHashId=enrollhash.id).first()
        if usrcommand.lower() == 'applyrestrictions':
            if 'data' not in request.POST or not request.POST['data']:
                jsonResponse["status_code"] = 400
                jsonResponse["message"] = "This command requires 'data' variable with json object"
                try:
                    failedCommand = FailedCommand(childHash=childhash, status_code=400, commandData=jsonResponse)
                    failedCommand.save()
                except IntegrityError:
                    pass
                return JResponse(jsonResponse)
            try:
                resdict = json.loads(request.POST['data'])
            except Exception:
                jsonResponse["status_code"] = 400
                jsonResponse["message"] = "Invalid json object for current command"
                try:
                    failedCommand = FailedCommand(childHash=childhash, status_code=400, commandData=jsonResponse)
                    failedCommand.save()
                except IntegrityError:
                    pass
                return JResponse(jsonResponse)
            allowedRestrictions = Restrictions.restrictionsMapping()
            if not all(item in allowedRestrictions.keys() for item in resdict.keys()):
                jsonResponse["status_code"] = 400
                jsonResponse["message"] = "Invalid keys in json object"
                try:
                    failedCommand = FailedCommand(childHash=childhash, status_code=400, commandData=jsonResponse)
                    failedCommand.save()
                except IntegrityError:
                    pass
                return JResponse(jsonResponse)
            try:
                currentRestrictionsObj = Restrictions.objects.get(childId=child)
            except Restrictions.DoesNotExist:
                currentRestrictionsObj = None


It run perfectly on local with staging database.
But when I request on staging i face this error but not on local Please tell me what i do.

TypeError at /mdm/processcommand/
'EnrollHash' object is not subscriptable

Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://stgmdm.familytime.io/mdm/processcommand/
Django Version: 3.2.12
Python Executable: /usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.16
Python Path: ['/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm', '/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/bin', '/usr/lib64/python39.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.9', '/usr/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/mdm/views.py", in inner

  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/mdm/mdm/views.py", line 224, in processCommand
    except Child.DoesNotExist:

Exception Type: TypeError at /mdm/processcommand/
Exception Value: 'EnrollHash' object is not subscriptable

Both I use same DB locally i use staging DB.
I try this with locally no face error but when i push and deploy on EC2 Amazone Linux I faced the problem i explaind.
